# JS - Can I import same named exports with multiple files?

Tags: javascript

For example

`File A`

```js
export const hello = {...something}
```

`File B`

```js
// export name is same to File A
export const hello = {...another}
```

and `Index.js`

```
// want to import File A and File B's hello module like below
import { hello } from './File A', 'File B';

// Iterable like array, object or else
const mergedHello = hello;
```

I want to import all `hello` from same directory dynamically.

If there are 100 files with `export hello`, 100 lines of import is something weird...

Is this possible or any proper module?

I cannot find suitable js module..

Comment: Is this a NodeJS app or a browser app or something else? If you have access to the file system at runtime like in a Node app you can use the `fs` module to enumerate the directory and import the results dynamically. This is a weird thing to be doing except in rare circumstances. Can you explain your use case?

Comment: I'm using in Node app, and I resolved this problems. Thanks for your comment, and I'll try  `fs` module when possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's not possible, you can create another module which export all other like this:

```
export {hello as helloA} from './FileA'
export {hello as helloB} from './FileB'
...
```

And then in the `Index` file you could import them like:

```
import * as hello from './module'
```

Or if you want some of them:

```
import {helloA, helloB} from './module'
```